# What are the effective ways to exchange files on different servers with Shell Script?

Tags: shell, authorization, exchange-server

I want to update some file in a server, with an automated script and the target files on a different server. Haven't started yet, but I think there will be authorization and connection issues during the process. Any suggestion on how I could approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up ssh keys so that you do not need a password.  You can then use `scp` or `rsync`.

More sophisticated systems:

- [chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home)
- capistrano

Answer (score 1):

- Easiest solution is cross-mounting the filesystem (e.g. NFS) across servers.
- If your servers support rcp/rsh, you can use .rhosts file to allow automated connection.
- If only ssh/sftp/scp is available, Google for automated ssh/sftp - it is doable but trickier to set up.